# Retrieve history data from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Android Development I am retrieving all Child nodes from firebase Realtime database whose appointment status is "Completed" and child has current user id but when i moved to the history it didn't show anything. Can anyone help me solve this issue.. I need the solution as soon as possible.

```
if (reference != null) {

            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    if (snapshot.exists()) {
                        appointmentList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            id = ds.getKey();
                            if (ds.child("appointmentStatus").getValue(String.class).equals("Completed")) {


                                appointmentList.add(ds.getValue(Appointment.class));

                                SalHistory history = new SalHistory(appointmentList);
                                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.saloonHistoryRecycler);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(history);

                            }

                        }

                    }
```

Firebase Database Model

[image]

Comment: whta you want now, explain

Comment: I want to retrieve all the requests of current user who is logged in into my history activity... and whose appointment Status is completed.

Comment: so you want to retrieve all entries whose appointment status is completed??

Comment: Yes right... if current user who have the entries then it will be retrieve otherwise it will be empty and yes you can make condition because in every entery i have current user id ... known as saloon id aur customer id ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OrderbyChild to fetch items from Firebase based on appointmentStatus

```
reference.orderByChild("appointmentStatus").equalTo("Completed).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
   
                                }
    
                            }
    
                        }
```

Comment: Ok but one more thing that i have 3 saloons and each saloon has request or entries that has status completed.. So i am trying to say that when i am logged in to any of saloon screen then only those requests will be retrieved that is related to that particular saloon.

Comment: then you have to fetch based on saloonid

Comment: yes right. but i don't know how. can you do this code for me ? @Wahdat Kashmiri

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkBxe.png .. Please have a look into it.

Comment: i am asking locally , how

Comment: Sorry bro i cant understand what you are asking as i am new.. Can you come on anydesk access my system and check ?

Comment: Ok i am available now... Are you there ?